# Productive use of SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, signals

Are there many productive uses of handling SIGSEGV, other than a last ditch "something bad happened"?

From the [SIGSEGV wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV), debuggers use it to catch errors in a user's program and inform the user of what happened. The way that I see it, it's a way to query the virtual memory system, and since we have a virtual memory system, I feel like SIGSEGV could be used in a more productive way. One thing I thought of was that you could have a stack somewhere, try to put things onto it, and then when you catch a SIGSEGV, increase the size of the stack, and retry the operation. I feel like this could be useful if, for example, you are processing messages and yet don't know the size of your messages but due to speed, you want to be optimistic about writing them to memory.

Is this a legitimate use of the signal? Are there other ways to incorporate it into your software design as a method of control flow and execution rather than as a last ditch method of error handling?

Comment: In your example, you would presumably already know the stack size and the current position of the stack pointer, so you would know ahead of time whether a given operation would overflow the stack,.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I might be mistaken, but I don't think his example presumes knowing the stack size.  In fact, I thought this method was already used in some OS' to grow stacks.

Comment: What's productive about a segfault is that it allows the operating system to terminate a program whose internal state is so corrupted that the processor cannot meaningfully continue executing code.  Turning state corruption into a program feature is not productive.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The one place I've come across this it was done in the language runtime library which would check if the function it was entering required more stack than was left, then grab enough to satisfy the extra. It didn't rely on causing and recovering from a program crash. This also resulted in a rather interesting non-contiguous stack

Comment: @TomTanner: I was only partially right, Windows uses `STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION` for stack growth, [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366549(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: it doesn't say that. it says "some systems can".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical usage is to catch access to specific memory locations.

You set up memory access rights with `mprotect`, then you handle the fault, give access, and continue the execution. This can be used for debugging, creative logging, custom i/o-memory mapping, ...

Comment: Can you give some example code from which one can see how this would work? I am especially interested in how to continue the execution normally after the access to the specific memory page has been recorded by the signal handler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142951/how-can-i-protect-a-heap-memory-in-linux

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Debuggers don't "use" SIGSEGV to catch faults in a user program. Debuggers trap the event so that you (the programmer) can see what has happened.

You really don't want to use SIGSEGV like that. It would be incredibly slow. When a memory violation happens, the O/S has to check if it is a valid access to memory that is currently paged out of the system, as opposed to something you shouldn't be accessing.

You'd have to make similar checks after the operating system had decided you shouldn't be doing that, to check whether or not you were accessing the wrong place on the stack, and decide whether or not it was because the stack needed expanding. Moreover it is unlikely you'd be able to return to the instruction that caused the access violation to re-execute it. You normally have to be the O/S to do that.

If it did work, the code needed would be highly compiler, O/S and architecture specific.

Basically, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The productive uses of SIGSEGV and other signals are typically limited in production environments due to portability concerns. The list of things you can do safely in a signal handler is pretty short, and the interaction between threads and signals is largely unspecified.

For this reason, the use of SIGSEGV is usually limited to debuggers and similar programs that have to run unknown code without changing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the production environment context it is useful to handle `SIGSEGV` - to log a message and handle the shutdown gracefully (shutdown network connections etc, perhaps having a restart).

Comment: Is it safe to do any of that after a SIGSEGV?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - Yes. Create a space at the start to place that information in. Then set up the handler. i.e. a `struct` for file descriptors at the start that you may require. It enables the program to close down more gracefully and also might  give you more information that sometimes you do not get from the development environment